# Directive is not loading on vs code

Tags: angular

[image]

While creating a nested component, The Directive module is not being complied by the angular2. I am a learner, please let me know if the question needs better presentation

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

The directives inside the `@Component` must be declared as an `array` but you are giving it a typeof `HomeComponent[]`

It should be like this:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: 'my template',
 directives: [ HomeComponent ] //<-- like this or remove it completely to declare it in @NgModule
})
```

Also make sure that you include it in your declatrations inside the `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent ],  //<-- here
  providers:    [],      
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```